# How to clearInterval in a if else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make little Countdown Timer. When the user click the button, the timer begin and set `isTiming` to true, then when the user click the button again, the timer stops and set `isTiming` to false. The problem is that the `timeInterval` was not cleared when I click the button to stop the Timer. I logged the `timeInterval` and found it to be `undefined`. Where did I go wrong?

```
$("#time-count").click(function() {
  if (!isTiming) {
    isTiming = true;

    $( "#minus" ).fadeOut();
    $( "#plus" ).fadeOut();
    $( "div#inner" ).css("animation", "loader" + " " + String(60 * Number($("#time-count").text())) + "s ease-out");
    $(this).text($(this).text() + ":" + "00")

    //set the timeInterval
    var timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      var t = formatTimeRemaining($("#time-count").text());  

      if (t.sec.length === 1) {
        $("#time-count").text(t.min + ":" + "0" + t.sec);
      }else {
        $("#time-count").text(t.min + ":" + t.sec);
      }
      if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeInterval);
      }
    }, 1000)

  }else {
    isTiming = false;

    //Try to clearInterval here but fail
    clearInterval(timeInterval);
    $("#time-count").text("20");
    $( "#minus" ).fadeIn();
    $( "#plus" ).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

You can have a look at my [code](http://codepen.io/luiyezheng/pen/LZPvmJ) on CodePen

Comment: You need to declare `var timeInterval` in outer scope, because, once your click event handler is processed, its inner variables, including `timeInterval` is forgotten. If you define `timeInterval` in outer scope of your click handler, then it will be persistent between calls of that handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeInterval` needs to be global, otherwise you have a local variable every time you click.

Answer (score 1):

`timeinterval` is defined only in the if-then part of the statement, not in the else part. Put the `var` in the beginning of the function and only assign the value from `setInterval` where it is now.

Answer (score 1):

declare your timeinterval outside of your if it limits variable scope